# Trying to ID a background music track from either Star Wars: Battlefront (2004) or Star Wars: Battlefront II (2005)

Tags: star-wars, music-identification, star-wars-battlefront

There’s this ambient song from a level in one of these games with female vocals. It was very somber as opposed to the usual exciting and bombastic sound of other tracks. I’m trying to identify it from when I heard it as a kid, which is the last time I heard it, but have had no luck with browsing the soundtrack MP3s or YouTube videos. I loosely remember the level having a sophisticated look to it, I was on a catwalk looking at another catwalk and I believe it was indoors. The scenery was white.

Edit: it’s similar to the Halo 4 theme.

Comment: I recommend searching YouTube for a video featuring the music in question, or at least a visual of the level the music was used in, and then editing your answer to include a link to said video. As things stand, people might have a tough time determining which _level_ you're actually talking about, never mind identifying the music used in that level.

Comment: @LogicDictates That would be helpful but I’ve already searched through the wiki and mp3 lists and can’t seem to find the map the track plays in. I realize this is a difficult request but that’s why I’ve turned to message boards since I’ve had no luck whatsoever in my own search. I probably wouldn’t have turned to forums if I had the info you recommend.

Comment: Did you try searching OST at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UPX8AOz3K64&list=OLAK5uy_k0yKvlUubRfnvQbX1Gxy1uovsM7dp3YPk (Gordy Haab)?

Comment: @Slweetch - When I use the search term "star wars battlefront playthrough" on YouTube, several multi-hour-long videos come up with what I presume are complete playthroughs of the games in question. Surely at least one of these videos would contain footage (and likely audio) of the level in question?

Comment: @Yaroslav Kornachevskyi yes I’ve browsed not only YouTube OST for both games but in depth mp3s’ and haven’t found it. As for the game OST you provided, that’s the wrong game. The track I’m referring to resides in the classic Star Wars battlefront games.

Comment: @LogicDictates I’ll give it a shot

Comment: "Less bombastic" would seem to leave out Duel of the Fates and Battle of the Heroes. Was it perhaps this track, "Swim to Ototh Gunga" from The Phantom Menace? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1kaRj_Kv1nQ

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 I think you’re on the right track with this one though I’m sorry to say it’s not it.

Comment: @Slweetch There are a few more tracks from Episode I with a similar theme, all for the underwater Naboo bits. Tracks 8-12 on the Ultimate Edition CD: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_I:_The_Phantom_Menace_(soundtrack) . There's also a lot of unreleased music from the Prequel trilogy that's been put into video games; it's possible the music you're looking for is some of that.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be **Padmé's Ruminations**? I know this plays on a few maps in Battlefront II, although not in the first game since it predates *Revenge of the Sith*.

I looked up the [Halo 4 theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_FY8uedFyIk) and it does sound a bit similar. It's also the only prequel soundtrack piece that I know of with female vocals (besides the Otoh Gunga piece that you ruled out in the comments). I'm not sure which map you might have heard it on, although the soundtrack is often randomized and it could have been Kamino or the Death Star.

The version used in the film can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_hoXNXSpmng).